# How can 2 or more users develop for 1 heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I and one other person is developing a rails app.

Does heroku allow multiple users to manage a single app?

If not, is the only solution sharing a heroku account for 2 of us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the second developer as a collaborator using either the web interface or the cli: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing